# sqlite function that delete row (java)

Tags: java, sqlite

I am an SQL beginner. I have to write in sqlite a function that gets a db file. The db file contains a lot of tables. The function needs to search in the age column. When there is a age that lower than 20 I need to delete the row.

for example:
first table:

```
age - name      
40  - Din   
12  - Tayler  
60  - George
```

second table:

```
id -  name  - country  - age 

1  -  obama - usa      - 45
2  -  ari   - austarlia- 7
```

after running the function:

first table:

```
age - name      
40  - Din       
60  - George
```

second table:

```
 id - name  - country - age 

 1  - obama - usa     - 45
```

I started the code (in the Picture attached
[there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNwdl.png))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be broken down into the following steps:
1. Find all the table names.
2. Loop through each table and delete the row which has age less than 20.

I added the following code, however you might need to customise it based on your requirements.

```
public class UpdateDB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection c = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Andrei/test.db");

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'";

            Statement stmt  = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<>();

            // loop through the result set
            while (rs.next()) {
                tableNames.add(rs.getString(3));
            }

            System.out.println("BEFORE UPDATE");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");

            for (String table: tableNames) {

                String sqlUpdate = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " ";
                ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sqlUpdate);

                while(rs2.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs2.getInt("ID") + " " + rs2.getString("AGE"));
                }
            }

            // This is the statement which deletes the rows
            for (String table: tableNames) {
                String sqlUpdate = "DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE AGE < 20";
                stmt.executeUpdate(sqlUpdate);
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("AFTER UPDATE");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");

            for (String table: tableNames) {

                String sqlUpdate = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " ";
                ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sqlUpdate);

                while(rs2.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs2.getInt("ID") + " " + rs2.getString("AGE"));
                }
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UpdateDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UpdateDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you for the explaintion... but I don't undestand some issues:            1. what is the result rs? (and why did you do rs.getstring(3)?                   2. What is the for loop in the end ? I didn't understand what is it doing?       3.  why did you work with the id? In the first table it doesn't have id ?! Thank you!

Comment: 1. the rs stores the result of the sql query that returns the list of all the tables in the database. I found that the 3rd column returns the name of the table. You can look up the documentation for the other columns. 2. The purpose of the loop is to iterate over the list of table names and replace the table name in the sqlUpdate query. 3. I used id because I built two dummy tables to test the code. As I mentioned in the post, you will need to customise the code to fit your requirements. The structure of my tables is: had id, name, age (table1) and id,name,address, age (table2).